# receive certain serial data from com port c#

Tags: c#, serial-port, led

We needed to change the text on a a led panel brought around 7-9 years ago. Hence, long story short, we needed an app for that. The panel has a serial connection. Everything is welded inside a hardcover box. The panel works fine but we need to change the text shown.

Now the thing is, the panel displays temperature taken via a thermometer inside, along with the regular text. I want to receive the text displayed and the temperature, change it in my app then send it back.

Apparently, I can send data after opening serial con as `serialPort1.Write(...` and read in a similar fashion but I don't think the panel is meant to send any data. I have no idea what is in the box but I am sure it is the simplest of devices. Will it help if I cut open the box? Are there resources I can read to learn how to read and change the text displayed on a panel through serial connection.

**EDIT**:
The panel has some kind of storage I suppose, since the text shows without computer connection and even after unplugging.

Comment: The device probably has proprietary software that displays the text and will expect to read it from the internal memory in some format. I doubt there will be a generic solution to this. Do you have a manual or any information about the device? Each system will have it's own way of storing and displaying the data so just being able to read / write from a serial port doesn't mean the display will change unless you know what the device expects from that port.

Comment: Well there is an application provided by the seller but It doesn't work. It is awful work with no read me's/manuals (nothing at all). As a last resort, I'm going to try to decompile that app and try fixing it. I'll try serial connection and see what happens tonight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text shown might be read from an onboard memory of the microcontroller and you cannot change that through serial, it's controlled by the code run by the controller.

Comment: It has an application (which doesn't work) thats why I have hope.

Comment: I could not change it allright. But why does it have a serial output if I can't change anything. All serial connections froze. Also, I have learnt that windows 8 has major problems with Prolific USB-Serial Drivers. An absolute nightmare!

Comment: It might have that serial interface to diagnose it. To obtain more info than what is provided via the LCD.